# Upgraded to OS X Mavericks and now XCode can't find <iostream>

Tags: c++, xcode, osx-mavericks

So I previously had all my libraries working fine—until I upgraded to OS X Mavericks. I've researched the matter here on StackOverflow as well as some Apple discussion forums, but none of the fixes really worked. Is there anything I can do to remedy this? Thank you.

Comment: Since we don't know the remedies you tried, and frankly asking us to hunt down the potential solutions on the Apple forums and toss them out by association is ridiculous, it isn't possible to concisely answer this question. At best we'd be telling you that which you *may* have already done. That said, were it I, I would uninstall Xcode *entirely* and reinstall from scratch (and thats probably in the list, so count that as redundancy #1). I did install Mavericks, and the Xcode update as well, without issue, so I count myself fortunate to be apparently running smoothly.

Comment: My apologies. I know you aren't trying to be mean, and I'll use this as a learning experience. I'm being the kind of person that annoys me, so I feel your pain. That said, I'll attempt to resolve these issues.

1) I tried going to the Apple Developer Store and downloaded the Command Line Tools for Late October. 
2) I tried running xcode-select --install. The error message said it couldn't find the update.
3) I downloaded clang+llvm-3.3-x86_64-apple-darwin12.tar.gz off the internet and tried to extract it.
4) I upgraded to the latest version of Xcode.
5) I restarted my computer.
Thanks; sorry.

Comment: Egads thats a helluva chain. Now I seriously do feel fortunate to not have to go through that. The scorched-earth approach is always there (I mentioned it) but I'd save it as an all-else-fails situation, which may be approaching sooner than we'd like. If it helps at all, "`Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)`" is my current `clang --version` report. Dunno what you're getting. Note: I have *strictly* updated through the App Store since I installed Xcode on my Macbook Air (mid2011) shortly after purchase, including using the feature installer for the cmdline tools.

Comment: What's the status on this? I would like to upgrade but am obviously now concerned. Did you get it to work?